# Problem with logical partition and recovery mode

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, compiz

After the installation of compiz with linux mint, I had a problem in my Linux Mint 14 . There is a blank screen after typing my login/password to enter my session. I tried some things to correct this. But at the end I decided to use unetbootin, and install Mint 15. I clicked on Install Mint 15 and I choosed : Install Mint15 at the same partition of Mint14, so it will erase everything on the system partition (not my home partition) . In the screen of choosing the country, I canceled the installation (it has not started, as far as I know) .

After that, when checking for mounted partitions, I didn't found the home partition (sda5) . I just found the physical partition (sda1) which used to contain the boot loader and the whole system . ps: I used to have a home partition, which is a logical partition (sda5)

Now I am trying to enter the recovery mode to make a scan and correct disk errors, but I can't since after clicking shift , the laptop enter a black screen and freezes .

Any suggestion ? At least how to enter the recovery mode, this can help me .

Edit : fdisk output image :

[image]

Comment: When is it that you press `shift`? Why is pressing shift necessary? Can you boot into your normal system? If so, can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? What you describe should not have affected your disk in any way, the likeloest problem is that your `/home` is not being mounted for some reason but it should still exist.

Comment: Pressing Shift is to enter the recovery mode .
I can't boot in normal system, but I will try to boot in root shell . I hope that my /home still exists .

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I can't also access to root shell, since it is also accessible via recovery mode.
To summarize , I can't access nothing (graphical desktop, recovery mode, root shell) right now.

Comment: So, you're saying that you press shift in the bootloader (grub) screen, and that causes a black screen? Strange. You could try booting a Live CD or booting your normal session and hitting Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get to a terminal.

Comment: I am booting with Ubuntu rescue remix, and executing testdisk utility on sda1 to find the lost partition (sda5 or home/)

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l` first, the partition will probably be listed, just no mounted.

Comment: This is a photo of the output http://i.imgur.com/txgrdSe.jpg , hope it helps .

Comment: I think my home is sda2 because sda5 is the swap . I was thinking that it was sda5 . So I should make mount /dev/sda2 /home -t ext4 . The error was : ` wrong fs type bad option bad superblock missing codepage or helper program or other error . In some cases useful info is found in syslog `